OpenCV WND_PROP_TOPMOST property doesn't turn off once enabled
I am setting a window to always display on top using the following command in Python. I would like this setting to be toggleable, however I am not able to "unset" this property once it has been set.
import cv2
import numpy as np

frame = np.zeros((240, 320, 3), np.uint8)
window = "Test Window"

def show_window(window, frame):
    print(cv2.getWindowProperty(window, cv2.WND_PROP_TOPMOST))
    while(True):
        cv2.imshow(window, frame)
        if cv2.waitKey() > 0:
            break

cv2.namedWindow(window)

cv2.setWindowProperty(window, cv2.WND_PROP_TOPMOST, 1)
show_window(window, frame)

cv2.setWindowProperty(window, cv2.WND_PROP_TOPMOST, 0)
show_window(window, frame)

This prints out
1.0
1.0

and the window remains in a top-most state (other windows won't appear above even if they have focus).

Did you actually run your [mcve] before posting it? Because that's going to crash on the third line (for two separate reasons, one being undefined variable, the other non-existent window), and lacks a cv2.waitKey... not to mention not really demonstrating the actual problem. (Something like this does tho: https://pastebin.com/raw/VJTNfGMD -- it even suggests that the property remains at value of 1.0 after the second call to setWindowProperty... interesting...)

I'm confident this is a bug. Writing an answer with a work-around, and I'll file an issue since the patch is quite trivial it seems.

I presume this is happening on MS Windows? (Geez, how did this get through the staging ground, I though that was meant to avoid such issues...)

No, @toyota-Supra, this has nothing to do with NumPy (it's just needed to make a dummy image to display), nor computer vision (just a bug in a utility function in a library). No need to add more tag abuse.

This looks like a bug, so let's prove it.
The implementation looks like this:
static bool setPropTopmost_(CvWindow& window, bool topmost)
{
    HWND flag    = topmost ? HWND_TOPMOST : HWND_TOP;
    BOOL success = SetWindowPos(window.frame, flag, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);

    // The rest is not relevant...
}

The first statement is key -- to enable the top-most state, it uses HWND_TOPMOST, and to disable it, it uses HWND_TOP and herein lies the problem.
If we refer to the documentation of SetWindowPos, we can see that for HWND_BOTTOM it does mention that

... If the hWnd parameter identifies a topmost window, the window loses its topmost status and is placed at the bottom of all other windows.

However, it does not say this for HWND_TOP, only that it places the window on the top. Furthermore, it mentions later on the page that (emphasis mine)

If a topmost window is repositioned to the bottom (HWND_BOTTOM) of the Z order or after any non-topmost window, it is no longer topmost.

Finally, there is the pseudo-handle HWND_NOTOPMOST described as (again emphasis mine)

Places the window above all non-topmost windows (that is, behind all topmost windows).

Therefore I conclude, that HWND_TOP is an incorrect way of making a window no longer top-most. Instead, HWND_NOTOPMOST should be used. This hypothesis can be easily verified using PyWin32, which lets us use Windows API directly from Python. We simply replace the cv2.setWindowProperty by a FindWindow followed by SetWindowPos with the right pseudo-handle.
import cv2
import numpy as np
import win32gui
import win32con

frame = np.zeros((240, 320, 3), np.uint8)
window = "Test Window"

def show_window(window, frame):
    print(cv2.getWindowProperty(window, cv2.WND_PROP_TOPMOST))
    while(True):
        cv2.imshow(window, frame)
        if cv2.waitKey() > 0:
            break

cv2.namedWindow(window)

cv2.setWindowProperty(window, cv2.WND_PROP_TOPMOST, 1)
show_window(window, frame)

wnd_handle = win32gui.FindWindow(None, window)  
win32gui.SetWindowPos(wnd_handle, win32con.HWND_NOTOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, win32con.SWP_NOMOVE + win32con.SWP_NOSIZE);

show_window(window, frame)

This prints
1.0
0.0

and indeed after pressing a key to get into the second stage, the window no longer remains top-most.



Bug reported: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/25833
PR submitted: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/25836
And merged, should be in release 4.11.

@IInspectable I don't follow. I definitely don't expect the Z order to change. I expect the style to go away, and it doesn't with HWND_TOP. (it still has the TOPMOST style, and behaves as such)

True, I misread this proposed answer. It does look like HWND_TOPMOST sets the WS_EX_TOPMOST window style and HWND_NOTOPMOST unsets it. All other (pseudo-)handles have no effect on this window style, and HWND_TOP is indeed the wrong one to use. I'll just delete that comment.
